# pyspark to_date fail to infer format

Tags: python, pyspark

I have a column of type string where the values are of the form  'Jun 2019'; 'Sep 2020'; etc.
I am trying to extract the year out of it, but it seems like to_date function fail to convert the data to datetime format

here is the code tried

```
df = df.withColumn('year_launch', year(to_date(df.launch)))
df.show()
```

Current outcome

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to pass the format of the date to the `to_date` function.

```
from pyspark.sql import functions as F

df.withColumn('year_launch', F.year(F.to_date("launch",  'MMM yyyy'))).show()
```

Output:

```
+--------+-----------+
|  launch|year_launch|
+--------+-----------+
|Jun 2019|       2019|
|Sep 2020|       2020|
|Jun 2021|       2021|
|Oct 2021|       2021|
+--------+-----------+
```